# I want to send a fixed number of bytes to represent numerical values that can be parsed as integer values

Tags: c++, serialization, arduino

I want to send multiple different integers in a group of consecutive bytes to an arduino to represent variable values for subsequent motor control. For example, I want the first 3 bytes to be able to store one single number that would range from 0 to lets say 1.000.000. then I want the next two bytes to be a smaller separate number. When I run this code with random binary numbers, I don't get any expected values.

```
byte data[14];
long accel1;
long accel2;
long spd1;
long spd2;
long pos1;
long pos2;

void loop () {
 if (Serial.available()){
  size_t numbytes = Serial.readBytes(data, 14);
    for(int i = 0;i<=14;i++){
      Serial.println(data[i]);
    }
    pos1 = readthreebytes(data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    pos2 = readthreebytes(data[4], data[5], data[6]);
    spd1 = readtwobytes(data[7], data[8]);
    spd2 = readtwobytes(data[9], data[10]);
    accel1 = readtwobytes(data[11], data[12]);
    accel2 = readtwobytes(data[13], data[14]);
 }
}

long readthreebytes(byte firstbyte, byte secondbyte, byte thirdbyte){
  long result = (firstbyte << 16) + (secondbyte << 8) + thirdbyte;
  return result;
}

long readtwobytes(byte firstbyte, byte secondbyte){
  long result = (firstbyte << 8) + secondbyte;
  return result;
}
```

If anyone could help me with this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the statements like `pos1 = data[1-4];` actually to what you want to do them?

Comment: that was just to visualize what I want. The first code is what I have currently. I'd prefer if the second set of code could work.

Comment: For the first six bytes, [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) perhaps? For the next three [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)? And some kind of loop for the `distance` perhaps?

Comment: @user10271487 This is very confusing. Replace that pseudo code with real one please.

Comment: I don't know if that command is valid in an arduino.

Comment: Or just wrap the code you have now with the assignments into a new function, `translateMessageToData` or something? And use a `struct` to contain all the data?

Comment: Well the point is I want a set number of bytes to represent one number. I can worry about over and underflow on the frontend. So I don't have to worry about leading zeroes or the size of bytes being sent changing during the program.

Comment: Anyone know how to use highbyte() and lowbyte() in arduino?

Comment: "I want to send a fixed number of bytes to represent numerical values that can be parsed as integer values" - So you wnt to define a network protocol and write functions to read and write data according to that protocol.

Comment: It doesn't have to be as involved as that. The number of bytes wont change, there won't be extra commands that will be sent that will have a different anatomy. I just want to make the first 3 bytes into one large integer that consists of 24 bits. and to be able to repeat that for subsequent bytes sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 long readthreebytes(byte firstbyte, byte secondbyte, byte thirdbyte){
  unsigned int result = (firstbyte << 16) + (secondbyte << 8) + thirdbyte;
  return result;
}
```

That just isn't going to work.  A byte is 8 bits in size.  If you shift that to the left by 16 bits you get 0 no matter what you started with.  Try casting your byte to long if you want to shift like that.

```
   long readthreebytes(byte firstbyte, byte secondbyte, byte thirdbyte){
  unsigned int result = ((unsigned long)firstbyte << 16) + ((unsigned long)secondbyte << 8) + thirdbyte;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Yep you were correct I believe. The variables firstbyte, secondbyte, and thirdbyte were the wrong data type. I changed them to unsigned long and it works so far.